# Counting views when video is click

Tags: ajax, laravel, bootstrap-modal

Here's the  situation. I have a project where I allow users to upload video. Whenever you click the video a Bootstrap-Modal pops up and the video automatically starts playing. Now I also implemented something where when the video is clicked and that is count as view because when you click the video it automatically starts. Now here is where I messed up, the view is counted when the modal opens up and that's not what I wanted, I wanted the view to be counted when you click the video. I will show you my code below. Can someone kindly help me fix this?

```
 //Video
<video class="video1" id="cx"  preload="auto" align="middle" data- 
toggle="modal"  data-target="#mymodal" data-user-id="{{$usero->id}}"
        data-video-src="{{$usero->intro_video}}"
        data-video-views="{{$usero->clicks}}"   style="  
   cursor:pointer;"><source  src="{{$usero->intro_video}}#t=15"  alt="Video 
   Unavailable"   id="" ></source>
```

```
  //Ajax request
  $('#mymodal').on('show.bs.modal show', function (event) {

var button = $(event.relatedTarget);


var user_id = button.data('user-id') ;
var video_src = button.data('video-src');
var video_views = button.data('video-views');


var modal = $(this);
modal.find('#video_source').attr('src', video_src);
modal.find('#video_views').text(video_views);

// send ajax request to increment video count
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'getmsg',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data : {
        requested_id: user_id
    },
    success: function(data){

    }
});
})
```

Comment: my suggestion is to stop video auto play, and then create your own html video tag , with then add an event listener to the play button, afterward you can send ajax request to the DB when user click play, see this library to create your custom video tag, you can utilize the source attribute to add video to the html markup - [HTML 5 Video Rocks Library](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/)

Comment: @NeonEmmanuel thank you for replying. after a playing around with the code for hours I found a solution and your answer helped me a bit. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

From the code samples you have provided I guess that you have another video tag in your modal, whose src attribute you are updating on show.bs.modal event.
If it the case you should give this video element an id ( video2 for example) and then you can call onplay event on this and you should put you ajax code in this event listner like this

```
$('#video2').onplay(function(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'getmsg',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data : {
            requested_id: user_id
        },
        success: function(data){

        }
    });
   });.
```

In addition you can update the view counts from the success handler of the ajax request if you want.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your answer helped me. After playing around with the code for hours I found a solution. I kind of followed what you did but a little different. But The only problem is that it's not doing one by one. Like say if I have multiple videos it will only do it for one video. Hope you understand what I'm saying. Can you help me with that

Comment: Hey @Supercoder54551, Have you get the exact solution to your problem? If not then please explain the exact scenario of your problem. Because in your previous comment you mention that you have multiple videos on the page so it is again somewhat confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I found the exact solution. My other problem is that when I'm trying to click the next video it doesn't show it only allows me to click the first video and not the next

Comment: Is it throwing any kind of error or warning in the console?

Comment: No I don't get any

Comment: Can you please provide me with the code snippet of the video/button which you are clicking?

Comment: @Raji Sorry for the late reply I've been looking a lot into my code and after playing around with the code I have managed to get it to do the next video. Thank you so much for taking the time out to help me. Thanks a bunch!